# Problems with horizontal aligment of figures using subcaption package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

The subfigures do not align horizontally, the (a) subfigure is placed approx. 3 cm lower then the (b)-figure. Can you please see what I'm doing wrong.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Coloured lines}
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Colourlines1}
     \caption{No treatment}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Colourlines2}
     \caption{Treatment}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that you're using the optional arguments `[a]` and `[b]` to the `subfigure` environments as a means to number the subfigures. Unfortunately, this won't work correctly because (i) the option is meant to be a location/alignment specifier rather than a numbering specifier and (ii) "`a`" is not a valid location specifier. (If you examine the log file that's produced by compiling your code, you'll find a warning message to this effect.) "`b`" just happens to work because it stands for "bottom". To align the subfigures, use either `[t]` ("top") or `[b]` ("bottom") as the location specifier for *both* subfigures.

Separately, the two `\centering` instructions you provide inside the `subfigure` environments aren't necessary because the graphs already take up the full widths of the respective environments. You may also want to insert a bit more whitespace between the two floats; I suggest you do so by adding the `\hspace{\fill}` directive.

The following, modified form of your MWE implements these ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option for real document
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Coloured lines}
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Colourlines1}
     \caption{No treatment}
   \end{subfigure}
   \hspace{\fill} % separate the two subfigures...
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Colourlines2}
     \caption{Treatment}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]